# C# How can I access a method that contains a foreach loop in my main?

Tags: c#, methods, foreach

I'd like to have it so that a list of names gets split, and then the first and last name gets split, so that each person's pair of first and last name is operated on. 
So, I have a list of names seperated by ';' that gets split into an array
In another class, I get this array, and using foreach, I split the char in the array by ',', giving me the first and last name.

I am wondering how I can call this last operation into the main so that my first and last names can eventually all each have their own operations carried out on.

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            pairInName funOperations = new pairInName();
            //I'd like to have the method from 'pairInName' to have the split list ',' (from the split list ';')
            //How can I run it so that it carries out the operation in my main()?
            //eventually, I'd like it so that it carries out a method in my main for each pair of first and last name, for each name in the list

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class namesList
    {
        public static string listOfNames = (
            "Tyrion,Lannister;" +
            "Euron,GreyJoy;" +
            "Davos,Seaworth;" +
            "Lord,Varys;" +
            "Samwell,Tarly;"
            );

        public static string[] splitListOfNames = listOfNames.Split(';');
    }

    public class pairInName
    {
        static void myOperations()
        {
            foreach (string champName in namesList.splitListOfNames)
            {
                string[] splitChampName = champName.Split(',');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AbdellahOUMGHAR but its not public.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary you are right, Thanks for remark :)

Answer (score 1):

The method marked as static, if you will also change the access modifier from `private` (default when not filling any modifier) to `public`, then you can access it directly.

```
pairInName.myOperations();
```

**Remark:** your complete structure isn't very OOP, you should consider refactor the design using classes and methods which more closer to the actual nature of the data context.

Create a `Character` entity will be a good start

```
public class Character
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public Character(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant because its not public... (btw not the downvoter)

Comment: Thanks for the observation, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your myOperations() as public , then you can use "pairInName.myOperations();" from main method .

Answer (score 0):

```
public class pairInName
{
    string[] splitChampName;
    public static void myOperations()
    {
        foreach (string champName in namesList.splitListOfNames)
        {
            splitChampName = champName.Split(',');
        }
    }

    public string[] getSplitResult
    {
        get { return splitChampName; }
    }
}
```